# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol - Recognise HTTP hits

Tags: android, google-analytics, protocols, measurement, measurement-protocol

I'm sending HTTP requests to Google Analytics using the Measurement Protocol and I am trying to make it so that I can customise the information that it receives. Currently, it shows that it's coming from an "Unknown Device" and displays a globe.

However, when using the Android SDK and running it through an app, it shows up with the name and title of the device that's being used.

While using the Measurement Protocol: is there any way to customise it from Unknown Device to a String that you can name it with an added protocol? There is no information on the API page which makes me think it's not possible.

Thanks

Comment: did you try to change User Agent correlated stuff (header or paramater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selvin was correct.

User Agent had to be changed to an existing User Agent String.